# Visual Studio 2010 indentation after for loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, indentation

Why am I getting this behavior right after the if block? Am I missing something?

```
for (;;)
    if (/*...*/)
    {
        // statements
    }

    // statements indented to match the if indentation instead of the for loop;
```

Comment: My guess is you had some unfinished statements within the `if() {...}` block when you started editing the statements after the if. A handy shortcut Ctrl A, then Ctrl K, then Ctrl F.

Comment: Nahh... tried it several times with different code. Same result. The block has to be closed with a '}' to be recognized apparently.

Comment: Perhaps you need to get VS 2010 SP1!

Comment: @Moron - lol.  I looked for one.  I would have busted a gut if there was one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the only way to keep VS doing indentation reasonably is to *always* use a block to enclose the statement controlled by a `for`, `if`, `while`, etc. In your case that would mean:

```
for (;;) 
{
    if (/* ... */)
    {
    // ...
    }
}
// further statements here indented to match for loop.
```

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio 2010 appears to be riddled with editor bugs.  Indentation is particularly hosed.

Just wait until it starts moving your cursor to the beginning of the line every time you type a ':'.

If you close the file and reopen it that sometimes fixes the issue...for a little while anyway.